# iOs Schedulers Multiplayer Network

Tags: ios, networking, multiplayer

I currently have an iOS fighting game that I am doing some networking for to allow multiplayer play. I am using GameCenter to transport data between the two devices, which in a later stage will be expanded to handle 4 devices at once.

My architecture for the network is as follows:

-Two clients find each other through GKMatch, a "Server" is determined by a random number generation, and the other device is the "Client". The server has final say on all the logic.

-For the client, I am detecting key presses, and sending these inputs to the server. At the same time I am also processing these inputs on the client and predicting (and displaying) the world as the client sees it. This makes the inputs feel fast and like a single player game with no delay. The client has a scheduler, which is set to happen 10x per second, which stores the current Game Object state (positions of all characters/projectiles), and stores it in an array with a sequence number being incremented.

-The server has a scheduler which sends a "Game Object" packet 10x a second. This Game Object also has a sequence number that is incremented for every packet it sends.

-The client receives these Game Object packets from the server, and compares the Game Object packet to the Game Object in it's array of the same sequence number.  Essentially comparing the servers world at time t to the clients world at time t. If there are any discrepancies, the client rolls back its world to that time dictated by the sequence number, adjusts the positions of the objects in the world, and then re-inputs all the clients key presses/inputs to get to the current time.

My problem is, 1.0/10.0 scheduler on my server, is slower than 1.0/10.0 scheduler on my client. The packets being sent are too far behind the packets being stored by the client. Going further and further out of time as time goes on.

Is there anyway to guarantee time?>?

Comment: network speed & stability affect the timing. Are you sure you want to do it in real time ? Suggest to do it in same Wi-Fi network